# Django template IF statement bug

Tags: html, django

Does anyone know how is this even possible that Django HTML-template file:

```
Length: {{ group_list|length }}
{% if group_list|length == 0 %}
  Show Foo
{% else %}
  Show Bar
{% endif %}
```

Returns:

```
Length: 0
Show Bar
```

Same problem on FF, Chrome and IE9+. This doesn't make any sense completely. How does one suppose to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `{% if group_list %}` instead of `{% if group_list|length == 0 %}`? Also are you sure if your `group_list` is an iterable?

Comment: Looks like your tip solved the issue - using `if` and `if not` instead of `==` works as expected. But still this is weird. Add answer, so I  can approve it.

Comment: Note you shouldn't expect different browsers to behave differently here anyway; template tags are resolved on the server before the browser ever sees it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you Daniel, I will notice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on with `{% if group_list|length == 0 %}`, but you can always use `if` statement to test the emptiness of the list:

```
{% if group_list %}
```

Note that django also has [length_is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#length-is) filter to test exact length, so your use case would most likely not supported by django.